# Change Time.timeScale during an animation event - Unity

Tags: unity, animation, timer

I have an animation. A few seconds after this animation starts I set an animation event that is correctly being triggered. This animation event calls a method where I am trying to modify `Time.timeScaleand` set it to 0.05f.

[image]

This event is calling the following method:

```
public void Slowmotion()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0.05f;
    //Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.02f;
}
```

But this `Slowmotion` method is not working.

Any ideas on what may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a scene based on your question and the "Slowmotion" method worked just fine, the steps I followed were:

1. Create a new scene in a project
2. Add a cube to the scene
3. Create a new **Animator Controller** asset
4. Add the **Animator** component to the cube and link the **Animator Controller** asset to it
5. Select the cube and open the **Animation** window
6. Create a new **Animation Clip** from the **Animation** window with a duration of 3 seconds and a simple movement curve
7. Create a new C# Script called *ChangeScale* with the following code:

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour {

       public void Slowmotion() {
           Time.timeScale = 0.05f;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Add the new script to the cube
9. Add an **Animation Event** calling the "Slowmotion" method:
   [image: Slowmotion Animation Event]
10. Press Play (In the main editor window, not the **Animation** window)

Hope this helps you find the issue in your setup